# linq projection

Tags: linq

I'm building a linq query using join and into statements.

```
var testmyquery = from uf in TheFolderModel.UserFolders
                where (uf.UserID == TheUserID)
                join ul in TheFolderModel.UserBooksheets on
                uf.FolderID equals ul.FolderID
                join ll in TheFolderModel.BooksheetBooks on
                ul.BooksheetID equals ll.BooksheetID
                join ua in TheFolderModel.BooksAppointments on
                ll.BookID equals ua.BookID
                group ua.BookID by uf.FolderID into Holdingvar
                orderby Holdingvar.Key
                select new { TheCount = Holdingvar.Count(), Holdingvar.Key };
```

I need to add columns from tables in uf and ul to the retuning object but once I've got a projection on Holdingvar, the intellisense doesn't give me access to uf or ul anymore when I'm in the select new{} statement. How do I add columns in the select statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
var testmyquery = from uf in TheFolderModel.UserFolders  
                where (uf.UserID == TheUserID)  
                join ul in TheFolderModel.UserBooksheets on  
                uf.FolderID equals ul.FolderID  
                join ll in TheFolderModel.BooksheetBooks on  
                ul.BooksheetID equals ll.BooksheetID  
                join ua in TheFolderModel.BooksAppointments on  
                ll.BookID equals ua.BookID  
                group ua.BookID by uf.FolderID into Holdingvar  
                orderby Holdingvar.Key   
                from uf2 in TheFolderModel.UserFolders
                where uf2.FolderID == testg.Key
                select new { testk = testg.Count(), testg.Key, uf2.FolderName };
```

I just needed to redefine a variable after I did the projection in the holding variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't...once you select new {..., the uf and ul are out of scope.

I'm not sure if this would work for you, but if you need the count and key, you could do a let statement:

```
var testmyquery = from uf in TheFolderModel.UserFolders
            where (uf.UserID == TheUserID)
            join ul in TheFolderModel.UserBooksheets on
            uf.FolderID equals ul.FolderID
            join ll in TheFolderModel.BooksheetBooks on
            ul.BooksheetID equals ll.BooksheetID
            join ua in TheFolderModel.BooksAppointments on
            ll.BookID equals ua.BookID
            group ua.BookID by uf.FolderID into Holdingvar
            orderby Holdingvar.Key
            let someproperty = new { TheCount = Holdingvar.Count(), Holdingvar.Key }
            select new { uf.UserID, ........ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time. Why is it not working for you? The structure of my query is a bit different. Perhaps you need to reform it?

```
var q = (from at in Repository.For<AuditTrailEntity>()
                 from att in Repository.For<AuditTrailTypeEntity>()
                 join ue in Repository.For<UserEntity>() on at.UserId equals ue.RowId
                 join up in Repository.For<UserProfileEntity>() on ue.AspnetUserId equals up.UserId
                 where (at.AffectedEntityName == "AssetEntity" && at.PKId == assetId.ToString() && at.ActionType == att.RowId)
                 orderby at.CreatedDate descending
                 select new AssetAuditTrailModel
                            {
                                RowId = at.RowId,
                                AffectedEntityName = at.AffectedEntityName,
                                PKId = at.PKId,
                                ActionType = at.ActionType,
                                ActionData = at.ActionData,
                                UserId = at.UserId,
                                CreatedDate = at.CreatedDate,
                                ActionName = att.FriendlyName,
                                UserName = up.FirstName + " " + up.LastName,
                            });
```